# What is the codec/modulation technique used in Google Tone?

Tags: audio, modulation, google-tone

[Google Tone](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2015/05/tone-experimental-chrome-extension-for.html) uses a codec that creates fairly pleasant sounding tones that convey information. What is the codec and/or modulation technique that is used?